# Pack smaller Rectangle in Bigger One with highest Repeat Count?

Tags: c++, bin-packing

i have a canvas rectangle ( constant width and height ) , i have child rectangle (also constant width and height) .
i want to fit the smaller rectangle in canvas with highest repeat count (or least wastage space Or maximize occupancy ratio ) .
when i tried famous algorithms like GuillotineBinPack or MaxRectsBinPack to fit lets say 25*20 rectangle in 70*100 all of them give me maximum of 13 rectangle instead of optimal result of 14 ( 5 first row + 5 second row + 4 third row).

Note : i tried all possible Heuristic permutations available with algorithm and even failed to achieve my optimal goal  .
any small hint will highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm using this algorithm, so far so good https://github.com/exad/boxologic